# Sub or function not defined excel vba error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying with a code and i am stuck in one step.

Error Message:

> "SUB  OR FUNCTION NOT DEFINED"

```
Sub searchterms()
On Error Resume Next
Dim c As Long
Dim VLPath As String
rw = ActiveWorkbook.Name
MP = InputBox("Please enter Marketplace", "AU/AE/BR/CA/CN/DE/ES/FR/IT/UK/US/IN/JP/MX/SG/TR")
Dim wb As Worksheet, rng As Range

lrr = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

 Set r = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    r.AutoFilter
    BN = r.Find(what:="recommended_browse_nodes", after:=r(1)).Column
    Kolumn = r.Find(what:="generic_keyword", after:=r(1)).Column
    r.AutoFilter Field:=Kolumn, Criteria1:="="

Workbooks.Open "C:\Macros\Consolidated BTG with Search Terms.xlsx"
nw = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Workbooks(nw).Activate
Workbooks(nw).Sheets(MP).Activate
Set Db = ActiveWorkbook
Workbooks(rw).Activate
Range(Cells(2, Kolumn), Cells(lrr, Kolumn)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.Formula = VLookup(Cells(lrr, BN), Workbooks(nw).Sheets(MP).Range("B2:D1000000"), 3, 0)
End Sub
```

Please help

Comment: If you want to actually write a formula to the range, you have to put the actual formula in a string: `"=VLOOKUP..."`

Comment: I have tried Selection.Formula = "=VLookup(Cells(lrr, BN), Workbooks(nw).Sheets(MP).Range("B2:D1000000"), 3, 0)" but its not giving any vlookup data

Comment: You need to build the formula, so `"=VLookup(" & Cells(lrr, BN) & "," & Workbooks(nw).Sheets(MP).Range("B2:D1000000").address & ", 3, 0)"` along those lines.  You'll need to play with the `workbooks(nw).name & !` too